# Why does ls give different output when piped

Tags: bash

Printing to terminal directly:

```
$ ls
a.out  avg.c  avg.h
```

Piping to `cat`

```
$ ls | cat
a.out
avg.c
avg.h
```

Why does `ls` give a different output based on destination?

Comment: FWIW, I consider this behaviour broken. The time-honored tradition of being easily able to string together huge pipelines of commands is made much harder when said commands change their ouput when it's sent to different places.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ls` can actually determine if it's outputting to a terminal or a file (with the `isatty` library call). If it detects a console, it will try to make it more compact for easier viewing.

Answer (score 6):

`ls` automatically behaves like `ls -1` when piped.

This is usually what you want when you are piping `ls` to `awk` or something like that, since it will treat the output of `ls` on a line-by-line basis.

To override this default behavior, you can use `ls -C | cat`.

Comment: Also, it ls doesn't use colours when piped. So if you want the colourful escape codes, you can use `ls -C --color=yes | cat`. It can be useful with `ls -C --color=yes | less -R`

Answer (score 1):

So that each line is one entry only, allowing the command the output is piped to to work as would likely be expected. For example (given your `ls` output), the following would probably not be what you want:

```
$ ls | sort -r
a.out  avg.c  avg.h
```

But because `sort` didn't know there was more than one item per line, it couldn't do anything. Compare this to what actually occurs:

```
$ ls | sort -r
avg.h
avg.c
a.out
```

You can achieve the (unexpected) first behavior by passing `-C` to `ls`.